# Where to put ansible pub key from linux host on Windows target?

Tags: ansible

I made a pub key on the host and copied it manually into the windows target:

```
C:\ProgramData\ssh\
```

and set permissions with

```
 .\FixHostFilePermissions.ps1
```

thinking that that would help... I still don't see how sshd is supposed to know when I log in, that it should use pubkey and bypass user account tho.

Is this an issue with the sshd_config on Windows target or do you do it some other way?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the public keys to an authorized_key file in the .ssh folder of the user’s profile directory.

[Ansible win32 openssh authentication](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/windows_setup.html#win32-openssh-authentication)

> Win32-OpenSSH authentication with Windows is similar to SSH authentication on Unix/Linux hosts. You can use a plaintext password or SSH public key authentication, add public keys to an authorized_key file in the .ssh folder of the user’s profile directory, and configure the service using the sshd_config file used by the SSH service as you would on a Unix/Linux host.

Comment: So it still says "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: user@host: Permission denied (publickey,password,keyboard-interactive)." when I use   ansible -u user all -m ping